# Why can't i use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http class in fetching data in laravel using Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Am new in consuming api. am trying to fecth data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts in Laravel but am getting error related to class not imported even though i have imported the Http Class used in the Laravel Docs.

this is my controller ***ApiController.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class ApiController extends Controller
{



public function fetch()
{
    $response = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    dd($response);
}


}
```

this is the error am receiving

```
"Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http' not found"
```

I have already installed the installed the Guzzle package. What am i doing wrong please.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.8.38

Comment: Try `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` and use `Client` instead of `HTTP`. You seem to be using the Laravel 7 way

Comment: Am getting this error ```Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Client::get()```

Comment: let me upgrade to Laravel 7 then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using the Laravel 7 way of using Guzzle. Change your Controller like so to make it work in Laravel 5.8

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function fetch()
    {
        $client = new Client;
        $request = $client->get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        $response = $request->getBody();

        dd($response);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** To get the contents of the request use `dd($response->getContents());` instead of `dd($response);`

Comment: just to clear confusion you can use $response->getBody()->getContents() to get contents